# Text is broken inside word

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

In my custom component, I'm facing a CSS issue. While I've set up the class `ion-text-wrap` on the component,it breaks inside some words.

Here is my component template

```html
<div class="ion-text-wrap history_main" 
    [style.width.px]="width" [style.height.px]="height"
>
    <span *ngFor="let singleElement of elements" class="moveEntry">{{singleElement.text}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is my component style

```css
.history_main {
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: beige;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.moveEntry {
    font-size: larger;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Here is the code-behind

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'loloof64-chesshistory',
  templateUrl: './loloof64-chesshistory.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loloof64-chesshistory.component.scss'],
})
export class Loloof64ChesshistoryComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() height = 200.0;
  @Input() width = 200.0;

  elements = [];

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef,) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  addMoveFan = (moveFan) => {
    this.elements.push({
      text: moveFan,
    });
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }

  clear = () => {
    this.elements = [];
  }

}
```

And a screenshot of the issue:

[image: Screenshot of the breaking issue]

Here you can a strange break on 'Kd3' at the end of the first line.

According to me, it has something to do with the use of Unicode characters, but even with that assumption I am unable to find a solution.

Here my conversion function from SAN to FAN

```js
convertSanToFan({moveSan, whiteTurn}) {
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/K/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2654' : '\u265A');
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/Q/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2655' : '\u265B');
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/R/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2656' : '\u265C');
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/B/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2657' : '\u265D');
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/N/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2658' : '\u265E');

    return moveSan;
  }
```

Maybe the use of Unicode could be improved so that the string is considered a whole word ?

Also notice that ion-text-nowrap class is not adapted since it keeps all elements on the same line.

Also tried with calling `.normalize()` on the produced string.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Hi ! In fact I expect each of move text to be set in the same line. Here Kd3 is split on the two lines.

Comment: Do you have two issues? 1. Wrong encoding made Kd3 to some <junk_char>d3 2. Line breaks the word into new line. Am I correct?

Comment: Maybe, in fact I use a string.replaceAll and regex in order to make the conversion from san move (without figurine) to fan (with figurine unicode). I've updated the answer

Comment: Ok, spread the answer

Comment: Added code to the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit : I ended up with the flexbox system, solving the issue**

```css
.history_main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    overflow: scroll;
    background-color: beige;
}
```

**Edit : in fact, this does not solve the issue.**

In fact the issue was with move san to move fan conversion method.
I needed to call normalize("NFD") after each conversion.

```js
  convertSanToFan({moveSan, whiteTurn}) {
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/K/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2654' : '\u265A').normalize("NFD");
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/Q/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2655' : '\u265B').normalize("NFD");
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/R/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2656' : '\u265C').normalize("NFD");
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/B/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2657' : '\u265D').normalize("NFD");
    moveSan = moveSan.replace(/N/g, whiteTurn ? '\u2658' : '\u265E').normalize("NFD");

    return moveSan;
  }
```

I've found thanks to @Ashokan suggestion in the comments.

Why NFD ? I don't know why this one exactly, just felt it is right.

[Mozilla Developper Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/String/normalize)

Comment: Do you really have to call the normalize function in every line or is it possible to just call it once when you return the string at the end?
Congratz for figuring this out btw!

Comment: I had to use it on every line. Anyway, this solution does not work. But i solved my issue using flexbox and flex-wrap property.

Answer (score 0):

From [ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities), i read:

> ```
> .ion-text-wrap    white-space: normal
> ```

maybe you wanted `white-space: no-break` instead?
try using this css on the element.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer. I don't understand all of your advice. Did you mean using the .ion-text-nowrap instead ? (I tried this one also without success, forgot to mention it). Or overriding the css ion-text-wrap ?

Comment: Because white-space: no-break is not in the list of the documentation

Comment: Also tried using `white-space: no-break;` directly, but did not solved my issue neither.